# Making Time Series/ Date DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time, time-series

I have a file with date time column 'A' with several months. I have to restrict to August 2017, group by the weekday, aggregate by summing. Set the Weekday column to numbers from one to seven. Then set the column Weekday as the (row) index. Return the resulting DataFrame.
I tried below:

```
pd.date_range("2017-08-01", "2017-08-31",freq='D').to_series()
```

y=z.dt.weekday

```
y

This gives
```

2017-08-01    1

```
2017-08-02    2
```

2017-08-03    3...
 and so forth but I am not able to rename or change the index of this single column in my jupyter notebook. How can I go about  solving this exercise.Please help.

Comment: `y=z.dt.weekday.rename('new_name')`.

Comment: Why both date and number data not appearing in different columns so that I can name them both separately and also make the number column as index.

Comment: Cos you are using series and not dataframes.

Comment: Is there any feature similar to or like to_DataFrame()???

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you'd like to have something like

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.date_range("2017-08-01", "2017-08-31",freq='D')\
       .to_frame(name="date")\
       .reset_index(drop=True)

df["n"] = np.random.randn(len(df))
df["dow"] = df["date"].dt.weekday

df.head()
```

```sh
        date         n  dow
0 2017-08-01  2.104356    1
1 2017-08-02  0.475884    2
2 2017-08-03 -0.849579    3
3 2017-08-04 -0.134266    4
4 2017-08-05 -1.322617    5
```

And then perform the following `groupby`

```py
df.groupby("dow")["n"].sum().reset_index()
```

```sh
   dow         n
0    0 -1.579067
1    1  0.793178
2    2 -2.310629
3    3 -2.275956
4    4 -0.091897
5    5 -3.918192
6    6 -2.252314
```

** Update **
If you have problems with `to_frame` you could define `df` as following

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range("2017-08-01",
                                         "2017-08-31",
                                         freq='D')})
```

Comment: Thank you but the code throws an error-'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Comment: I guess that depends on pd.__version__ do you mind to share your version?

Comment: I am using Python 3.

Comment: I was asking about panda version. Anyway I updated the part that was giving you an error. Check it out.